# Handling dynamically generated components in Plotly Dash with pattern matching callbacks

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I am looking for a solution to get event triggers from buttons dynamically added to a Div container. How do I use these button IDs in a single callback (i.e., a callback that can handle any possible number of dynamically generated IDs that can exist via user creation in the app)?

```
@app.callback(
        Output('button-container', 'children'),
        Input({'type': 'button', 'index': 'all'}, 'n_clicks'),
        State('button-container', 'children')
    )
    def update_button_text(n_clicks_list, button_children):
        ctx = dash.callback_context
        if not ctx.triggered:
            return button_children
        else:
            for i, button in enumerate(button_children):
                button_id = button['props']['id']
                n_clicks = n_clicks_list[i]['n_clicks']
                if button_id in ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id']:
                    button['props']['children'] = f'Button {n_clicks} clicked'
            return button_children
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here's an example using the [pattern matching callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks) feature in a Python Plotly Dash app:

> ***Note***: Dash 2.4+ required for use of `ctx.triggered_id`

```py
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, ctx
from dash import Dash, State, Input, Output, ALL, callback
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

app = dash.Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1(
            "Plotly Dash - After adding buttons to html.Div() via callback"
            ", how can we use these buttons as input to other callback"
        ),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Button(
                    f"Button {i}",
                    id={"type": "pattern-matched-button", "index": i},
                )
                for i in range(1, 6)  # Create 5 button components
            ]
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(
            id="buttons-response",
            children=[html.H2("No buttons clicked yet.")],
        ),
    ],
    style={"textAlign": "center"},
)


@callback(
    Output("buttons-response", "children"),
    Input({"type": "pattern-matched-button", "index": ALL}, "n_clicks"),
)
def display_output(button_clicks):
    if len(button_clicks) < 1:
        raise PreventUpdate
    n_clicks = ctx.triggered[0]["value"]
    if not n_clicks:
        raise PreventUpdate
    button_id = ctx.triggered_id.index
    return html.Div(
        [html.H2(f"Button {button_id} clicked {n_clicks} times.")]
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

which gives the following app functionality:
[image: Dash app with multiple button n_clicks inputs into one callback using pattern matching feature]

In this demo example, the number of button components is statically hard-coded; but, the same pattern-matching callback function could integrate with an additional (or multiple) callback that enabled dynamic component generation in the app by the user - which would be a typical use-case scenario for using the `ALL` feature in Dash callbacks.